# Android Navigation System

Tags: java, android, navigation, gps, maps

I have been asked to create a navigation system from scratch, that is not using google maps.

I already have the map of the city that I need to create the navigation system in autocad format.

I need to use this map somehow to create a navigation system but I dont really know where to start.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Edit:

The map that I have is just an autocad file, that is, there is no meta data. How do I generate the metadata for the map?

Secondly, the application must calculate the shortest path between two points and if the user does not respect the path, the system must re-calculate the path.

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, do you have meta data for your map or does this need to be generated? As in details about points, distances between them etc. Also, if its a navigation system, do you plan to use a shortest path algorithm to find the fastest route between two points? A little more detail would help.

Comment: Added the details you requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is interesting. Its practically the exact project I've been working on the last few months. Take a look at the README for the project. It details how to go about doing what you're asking.

https://github.com/NCM-Team/Navigating-Carnegie-Mellon

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I really appreciate it! I will surely go through it. Wish there was a way we could chat here so that I could get some startup guidance.

Comment: Well I'll tell you this. Its a hard project. Generating the data is a challenge by itself. Especially since you're mapping an entire city. After that you'll want to export it in a manner that can be parsed and used in code. Its going to take some work. You can always email me if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you can create a custom `SurfaceView`

```
public class MyMap extends SurfaceView {...
```

Next add this to your main layout:

```
<com.example.android.MyMap
     android:id="@+id/my_map"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Lastly, in your main `Activity`'s `onCreate(...)` method, add the line

```
MyMap map = (MyMap) findViewById(R.id.my_map);
```

You can now draw your map to this `SurfaceView`'s `Canvas`.